# Best way to get best breadcrumbs for Commerce

Tags: 7, commerce, breadcrumbs

When a user is checking the product page, the breadcrumb trail should give Home > Shop > Category > Product aka Home > Shop > Hats > A Hat

I used Crumbs, but it only gives me Home > Hats > A Hat and I cannot figure out how to include > Shop >.

Well obviously at the same time the breadcrumbs should also work fine in the rest of the pages like for contacts page it would be Home > Contacts

What would you recommend? What module? Or is it still possible with Crumbs and I am missing something?

Comment: The maintainer of Crumbs is usually quite open to support issues .. :)

Comment: The way Crumbs works, what you want to do is to specify "Shop" as a parent path for "Hats". If "Hats" is a taxonomy term, you can do that under Structure > Crumbs > Entity parent > Taxonomy.

Comment: Sorry donquixote, I solved this problem with Custom Breadcrumbs already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add breadcrumbs in your page using [drupal_get_breadcrumb](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_breadcrumb/7) and [drupal_set_breadcrumb](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_set_breadcrumb/7) function

In template.php

```
 function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {

        if(arg(0)=='shoppage'){  //Put appropriate condition 
            $breadcrumb = drupal_get_breadcrumb();
            $breadcrumb[1] = l('Shop', 'shop_link');
            $breadcrumb[2] = l('Category', 'category_link');
            drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So there's no module solution for that? If I implement this, will the rest for non shop pages work fine? Like Home > Contacts and etc.

Comment: Is you are writing separate function for shop pages OR have you created any template for shop pages?

Comment: You can write above code in your shop template file or you can write in template.php file by checking arguments for that particular pages

Comment: I'm not writing no functions and no custom templates.

Comment: I have updated code please check